# jQuery: HTML 5 canvas element can not be found

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

In my HTML I have:

```
<div id="cowcloud">
 <canvas id="cows" width="1024" height="253">
   <p>Browser doesn't support HTML5 canvas</p>
 </canvas>
</div>
```

I load a javascript file doing some jQuery stuff in the  section using the jQuery ready function. This has the following contents:

```
var cattle = [ 
                 {
                      "name" : "klara88",
                      "polygon" : {
                                       "vertices": [
                                          {"x" : "138", "y" : "204"}, 
                                          {"x" : "145", "y" : "201"},
                                          {"x" : "155", "y" : "178"}, 
                                          {"x" : "208", "y" : "177"},
                                          {"x" : "216", "y" : "200"}, 
                                          {"x" : "208", "y" : "192"},
                                          {"x" : "208", "y" : "218"}, 
                                          {"x" : "196", "y" : "219"},
                                          {"x" : "195", "y" : "206"}, 
                                          {"x" : "170", "y" : "202"},
                                          {"x" : "169", "y" : "219"}, 
                                          {"x" : "150", "y" : "217"}
                                       ]
                                }
                  }, 
              ];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cowcloud').click(function(e){
        [..]
        /* Search the cattle */
        $.each(cattle, function(i, cow) {
            [..]
            var context = $("#cows")[0].getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = '#0f0';
            context.beginPath();

            $.each(cow.polygon.vertices, function(i, vertex) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    context.moveTo(vertex.x, vertex.y);
                }
                else {
                    context.lineTo(vertex.x, vertex.y);
                }
            });
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        });

    });
 });
```

I cut some code away that was not relevant to this question.

The strange thing is that even when using the document ready function, jQuery is unable to find the canvas with id 'cows'. Also tried using plain javascript but then the element is null. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Well, if the browser does not support `<canvas>`, it is going to be ignored during HTML parsing (i.e. there'll be no `#cows` in the resulting DOM). What browser do you try it with? I've tested Chrome and the element is detected quite normally.

Comment: I'm using firefox 8.0 and chrome, same issue on both. The element is null for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this was a classical case of PEBKAC, in the code you didn't see I had:

```
$('#cowcloud').html('x: ' + point.x + ' y:' + point.y);
```

Which replaced the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should use

```
var context = $("#cows").get(0).getContext('2d');
```

instead of

```
var context = $("#cows")[0].getContext('2d');
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: Why do you still have `[0]` in there? Is there something I've never learned? This is pointing to an ID, unique.

Comment: @OptimusCrime `getContext()` is a native method of the `<canvas>` DOM object. You use `[0]` to return the first DOM object from the jQuery object. Using `get(0)` is wrong since that *again* returns a jQuery object (which won't have a method called `getContext()`).

Comment: No, `.get()` returns the DOM element. You're thinking of `.eq()`, which returns aa jQuery object.

Comment: But `[0]` is absolutely equivalent, so replacing it with `.get(0)` should have no effect.

Answer (score -1):

change this line

```
var context = $("#cows")[0].getContext('2d');
```

to

```
var context = $("#cows").getContext('2d');
```

Comment: That's false. jQuery "selector by ID" returns a jQuery array with a single object in it.

Comment: @Abdul: `$(selector)` *always* returns a jQuery object, whether it has zero, one, or a thousand DOM elements in it.